# C Wire in Air Handler

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

Can someone please help me find where to connect a C wire for my smart thermostat? Here are some pictures with descriptions. It is difficult to get to the 24v connection in the back. My schematic doesn’t show where the condensate pump would go so I am getting a little confused. A lot of other posts I have seen about this have much simpler setups.
[image]

[image]

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### That wirenut is as good a spot as any

Based on the information posted, I would try tapping the C wire at the wirenut you point out in your photo; it appears to be in the correct place in the circuit, and the wiring diagrams for your unit call out blue for C wires within the unit as well.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If it does not work, what is the worst that will happen? The thermostat will just tell me to connect a common wire?

Comment: @Chobes11 -- most likely, yes, either that or it simply won't power on